# Java crash on 32-bit Windows when launching Web Start application

Tags: java, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, java-web-start

At work we use a Personnel Administration System that uses Java Web Start.
We use Java 8.40, Internet Explorer 11 and Windows 7. Mostly 64-bit Windows but some 32-bit.
The computers with Windows 7 32-bit have trouble starting the application every morning. They have to try between 2 and 10 times before the application starts. Once they get in they can close the application and it will start without any problems.
Chrome usually works a little better but there is a policy at work that IE should be used.

I have followed Oracles Java troubleshooting guides and other online resources without any luck.

I have i.e.:

- checked Anti-Virus and Firewall configuration.
- made sure that Java is activated in the browser
- checked different configurations in Java Control Panel
- removed temporary files in IE and Java Control Panel
- I've made sure that we use 32-bit JRE
- tested to run IE without add-ons
- and a lot of other stuff

This [link](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=340427897) is one of the more useful ones I've found on fine tuning Java.

When I choose to Show Console in Java Control Panel and enabled tracing and logging, this is what happens when the application doesn't start:

- the console appears and starts to log events
- the console suddenly closes
- Java loading image never appears
- Java and Windows log files don't show any errors.

Although Java seems to crash there are no error files (hs_err_pid*) to be found  anywhere. I've searched the whole disk and even tried to set the JVM parameters to set a path for the error file (thanks Saeid)

I've also run [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) during the start of the application with filters on jp2launcher process and the path of the Java cache folder but that didn't give me any useful information.

I want to emphasize that the application eventually starts. The 32-bit users just have to try several times. The 64-bit users don't seem to have any problems.

This is what Process monitor shows at the moment when the Java Console Window abruptly closes:
[image: Process Monitor]

This is what the trace file look at the same moment:
[image]

and the log file:
[image]

Comment: what if you don't run the webstart application through browser? Simply download the .jnlp file of your webstart application and run it by double-clicking on it. See if you notice an improvement when you run it this way.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Haven't been at work. I'm not very good at Java and I don't really know how to locate the jnlp-file. In the trace file I can't see any reference to a jnlp-file just a bunch of jar-files.

Comment: Do you have a browser other than Internet Explorer? Internet Explorer tends to run jnlp files without downloading them, but if you use chrome, upon click on the webstart application button it should download the jnlp first, then ask you if you want to run it.

Comment: I do not see a jnlp-file in Chrome either. When the application has started it is shown in the taskbar as a Java Platform SE binary. Is it possible to start a Java application from a browser without a jnlp-file? I mean I separate application that does not run within a browser. I've tried to use Wireshark to look at the trafik but since it uses https it's hard to see,

Comment: Looks like the website is using Java Plugin to ensure the jnlp is never downloaded. You can still download the jnlp manually but you need to find the direct url to it. Try this: go to the page that launches the program, but instead of launching the program, right-click on the page and select "View page source" or "View source". Then in source pressing Ctrl+F to search for .jnlp to find the file url. Then copy and paste that url in your chrome browser to download the jnlp file.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any reference to a jnlp file in the source code. But I discovered that when I enter my credentials and click the login button, behind the scenes, it loads a jsp file that contains an applet-element with references to a lot of jar-files.

Comment: Looks like your jnlp runs in an indirect way. Reading your original post it appears that Java crashes. When a crash like this happens Java will create a log file: hs_err_pidxxxx.log where xxxx can be some number. If you start Internet Explorer from Desktop you should see this file created on desktop. See if you can find this file.

Comment: I've looked for a hs_err*.* in the whole disk without any luck. I added an IE shortcut on the desktop, if that is what you mean by starting IE from desktop. I also updated my question and added some images that shows what happens at the moment Java Crashes. I can't see any signs of errors.

Comment: If you open TaskManager, do you see a single jp2launcher process in there after running your webstart? If jp2launcher shows up briefly and then goes away it means JVM crashes and there should be a hs_err* file, but if it stays there then it didn't crash and is running normal. If the later is the case then the problem is with your Java code in which case you should whoever wrote your Java program to fix the problem.

Comment: The jp2launcher process appears in the Task Manager when I enter my credentials and then disappears after about 10 seconds. Still no sign of any hs_err* files though.

Comment: In that case jp2launcher probably crashes and it should generate hs_err* file. You can read more about hs_err* here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html In summary, you can add the following JVM parameter via Java Control Panel: -XX:ErrorFile=C:\test\java_error%p.log

Comment: What do you think about this https://community.oracle.com/thread/3676876 ?. It's pretty close to my problem. We don't have any problems with 64-bit Windows either.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like they're having an exact problem as you. I think now that it's confirmed that you're not the only one dealing with this problem it's safe to assume that this is a bug in Java. You may want to file report with Oracle. Unfortunately that may take more than a year. Alternatively you may be able to pay Oracle to fix it earlier. Here is their support 1-800 phone number and live chat: http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/price-lists/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Saeid, you've been very helpful. It's good to have some kind of explanation to the problem. By the way I added the parameter in Java Control Panel but still got no error files in the error folder. I also created the folder C:test.

Comment: You're very welcome. I understand how frustrating Java webstart can be sometimes.